# Spark 1.4 - Is HiveContext & SQLContext are the same in term of execution?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I am using zeppelin to execute queries against my spark cluster.
I have data in files which can be access via scala to DataFrame and then registered as a table OR through Hive (as the same file is registered as hive table)

In term of execution of the SQL code, is one faster then the other?

Here is the code sample for loading the data and registering as table:

```
    import sys.process._
// Zeppelin creates and injects sc (SparkContext) and sqlContext (HiveContext or SqlContext)
// So you don't need create them manually

val zeppelinHome = ("pwd" !!).replace("\n", "")
val bankText = sc.textFile(s"file://$zeppelinHome/data/bank-full.csv")

case class Bank(age: Integer, job: String, marital: String, education: String, balance: Integer)

val bank = bankText.map(s => s.split(";")).filter(s => s(0) != "\"age\"").map(
    s => Bank(s(0).toInt, 
            s(1).replaceAll("\"", ""),
            s(2).replaceAll("\"", ""),
            s(3).replaceAll("\"", ""),
            s(5).replaceAll("\"", "").toInt
        )
).toDF()
bank.registerTempTable("bank")
```

I assume I am using SQL and not HQL for both
Thanks!